# JSdoc trying to document a member of undocumented symbol

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am trying to use JSDoc in a Backbone Model, so I have the following `profile.js` file:

```
/** 
        A module representing a Profile.
        @exports models/profle
        @example
        // Load module
        require(['models/profile'], function(Profile) {
            var Myprofile = new Profile();
        });         
    */

define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    /** 
            @constructor
            @requires Backbone
            @augments module:Backbone.Model
        */

    var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend({
         /** 
                @lends profile.prototype
            */

        defaults: {
            PIN : null,
            is_guest: true,
            has_pin: false,
            imgSrc: null
        },

            /** 
                    Validate a Profile 
                    The validate method is passed the model attributes, as well as the options from set or save
                    @param {attrs} The attributes of the profile
                    @param {options} The options from set or save
                */
        validate: function(attrs, options) {
            if (!attrs.name || attrs.name.length == 0) 
                return 'You must enter a name!';

            if (!!attrs.name && attrs.name.length < 1 && attrs.name.length > 24)
                return "User name must be between 1 and 24 characters";

            if (!attrs.password || attrs.password.length != 4) 
                return "The pincode has to be four digits"; 

            if (!attrs.password || attrs.password != attrs.confirmPassword)
                return "Confirmed pincode does not match";          
        }

    });

    return Profile;

});
```

The problem is that when I do `jsdoc profile.js -d="home/mydocumentation" it generates a warning

**>> WARNING: Trying to document validate as a member of undocumented symbol profile.**

and it didn't document the validate function, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What specific version of jsdoc are you using? I can't reproduce what you describe with jsdoc 3.2.2. Also, you say that you did not document the ``validate`` function but there *is* a doclet just in front of it in the source you give in your question. ("Validate a profile[...]")

Comment: @Louis-DominiqueDubeau I install the jsdoc 3.3.0 and now there is no warning, but still the `validate` function is not documented, I am new to that tools, any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I misread "it" as "I" earlier. Using 3.2.2, I see ``validate`` documented in the output of jsdoc. I would advise against using 3.3.0 because that's a development version.